# Magento Customer Activation module hack customer group

Tags: php, magento

I installed a free extension that requires admin approval before a customer can log in. I am hacking it to try to get it to allow all customer groups except for one. I think the following is the function that I would edit, but when I do a test registration the test cookie does not show up in my console. Any ideas?

```
/**
     * Flag new accounts as such
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function customerSaveBefore($observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

        $storeId = Mage::helper('customeractivation')->getCustomerStoreId($customer);
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'); // var $session Mage_Customer_Model_Session
$customer_info = $session->getCustomer(); // var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
$userinfo = $customer_info->_origData; // fetch users info

// get user's customer group id number
$customer_group = $userinfo['group_id']; 
setcookie("Group", "yes");

        if (Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_MODULE_DISABLED, $storeId))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!$customer->getId())
        {
            $defaultStatus = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_DEFAULT_STATUS, $storeId);
            $customer->setCustomerActivated($defaultStatus);
            $customer->setCustomerActivationNewAccount(true);
        }
    }
```

My code is the:

```
$customer_info = $session->getCustomer(); // var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer
$userinfo = $customer_info->_origData; // fetch users info

// get user's customer group id number
$customer_group = $userinfo['group_id']; 
setcookie("Group", "yes");
```

Answer (score 0):

First: Please don't try to hack the module. Better create your own module rewriting the classes of the original module, so you'll still be able to update the original one.

Second: Are you sure that part of code is executed? What happens if you enter a die() in it?

Third: You can see a list of all triggered event by implementing the [firegento-debug](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-debug) module, so you could check if that event is really fired and the observer called.

Comment: How about copying it... and renaming it?? :D I'll look into this.

Comment: If you rename it you won't be able to get updates of the original module. Only rewriting is the right way, or calling observers on eventy if some are implemented.

Comment: I'm not sure I care about updates. My check events lists "customer_save_before  Netzarbeiter_CustomerActivation_Model_Observer
TNW_Salesforce_Model_Customer_Observer". I'm not sure how to use this debugger. How do I see what events are fired when a guest creates an account? I have installed the firegento and also the chromephp logger.

Comment: Did you activate the module? Can you see the list of events?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i was customizing the same extension.

The thing is your are not getting the customer group.

try this line for getting  the customer group

$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();

$groupId = $customer->getGroupId();